# How to correctly handle loading state in redux toolkit crud

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, react-state-management

I want to know the best way for handling the loading state in redux-toolkit.

I have this slice and here I can create a post, delete a post, get all posts.
And as I think, for all these operations I need to handle a loading state. So when the user waits for posts I can show a loader and if he creates a post I want to show a loader to him which indicates that the post is creating.

That's what I have

```
export const posts = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState : {posts: [], status: null},
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [createPost.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading"; <==== how to do this.
    },
    [createPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success"; <==== how to do this
    },
    [createPost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed"; <==== how to do this
    },

    [getPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading"; <==== how to do this
    },
    [getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success"; <==== how to do this
      state.posts = action.payload.data;
    },
    [getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed"; <==== how to do this
    },

    [deletePost.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading"; <==== how to do this
    },
    [deletePost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success"; <==== how to do this
      state.posts = state.posts.filter(el => el.id !== action.payload);
    },
    [deletePost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed"; <==== how to do this
    }, 

    [getPostById.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading"; <==== how to do this
    },
    [getPostById.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success"; <==== how to do this
      state.post = action.payload;
    },
    [getPostById.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed"; <==== how to do this
    },
  },
});
```

I can also create two more keys in my initial state for every crud operation like (createLoadingState, deleteLoadingState) but I think that's not right

I think that I can just make something like this:

```
[createPost.pending]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "creating_post_loading";
},
[createPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "creating_post_success";
},
[createPost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "creating_post_failed";
},


[getPosts.pending]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "get_posts_loading";
},
[getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "get_posts_success";
  state.posts = action.payload.data;
},
[getPosts.rejected]: (state, action) => {
  state.status = "get_posts_failed";
},
```

BUT then I will have to remember every single name, so this approach seems very bad for me.

The best idea that came up to my mind is to have this initialState

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  loading: null, <==== added
  error: null, <==== added
  selectedPost: {},
};
```

and now when I fetch all posts I just write **state.loading = true** BUT in **CREATE POST** I make state.loading = false since I don't want my posts to reload on the page if someone creates the post but in this way, I won't show a loader state for the created post since the loading state is false.

I can also create separate slices for each operation with its own loadingState but don't know if it is right.

What I mean, in my react component I check if posts are loading, if so then I show a loader and if not then I will show the fetched data but if I have the same loading state for all my crud operations then whenever the user adds/deletes/updates a post it will trigger the loading state for everything.

If you have github repos where I can find the best practices, I will be very happy if you can send me those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would either need many different loading indicators or even multiple slices, both which might be a lot of work. Redux Toolkit also contains a data fetching/api cache abstraction called "RTK Query" that automates all of that, so I recommend you read the docs on that.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview

Comment: The biggest cons for me when I tried to use that lib is - it's not possible to dispatch actions after response arrives inside of queries or mutations.

Comment: @Elisey well, there are already actions being dispatched for that, so you can just use those existing actions in your reducers (as shown in this example: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers). But of course you can also use the [`onQueryStarted`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted) lifecycle hook to wait for a response and then dispatch an action.